# Use I/O barriers to wait for PCI accesses to complete (PowerPC)

Tags: powerpc, memory-barriers, pci

I'm currently working on a problem related to memory barriers on a PPC e6500.

I am in a situation where I want to write something to the memory of my PCI device
and do a read back of the value immediately after. Additionally, I want to
be sure that the read back is correct and completely finished when the execution of my program continues.

Since PCI (not PCIe) supports re-ordering of read/writes depending on situation during the access,
I am pretty sure I need I/O barriers to achieve this safely and consistently. However, I am not sure which exact sequence and what barriers I need to use on my PPC.

As I've understood the asm instruction `eieio`only ensures that accesses are done in the
correct order but it does not ensure that all instructions previous to the `eieio` are finished when it has completed.

However, the asm `sync` instruction seems to complete only when all previous instructions
are completely finished.

This leads me to the assumption that the code should look something like this:

```
Write to PCI device memory
eieio
Read from PCI device memory
sync
continue
```

Is this the correct approach or did I understand something wrong regarding memory barriers on PPC?

Thank you very much,
Michael